# SQL Delete All Data

Tags: mysql, sql, twitter-follow

I am trying to delete all the data for users with fewer than 10 followers and more than 1000 followers. I got this query by far:

```
DELETE FROM Test 
WHERE Followers 
BETWEEN 1 AND 9
```

This query deletes the data for users under 10 followers. How do I delete users with more than 1000 followers? Can I have both queries in one.

Comment: Does Followers contain 0 or less?

Comment: Sorry didn't have time to answer no followers are between 1 and 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you do not `DELETE *` That would imply that you have to tell it which columns to `DELETE` from a row. You However are deleting and entire row and therefore do not have to specify `*`

```
DELETE FROM Test 
WHERE (Followers >=1 
AND Followers <10)
OR Followers >1000
```

Comment: You could also use `WHERE Followers NOT BETWEEN 10 AND 1000;`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Since `Followers` field contains only values that are > 0:

```
DELETE FROM Test 
WHERE Followers <10 
OR Followers >1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this second condition to your query with `OR`

```
DELETE
  FROM Test 
 WHERE Followers BETWEEN 1 AND 9
       OR Followers > 1000;
```

Comment: Your original still said `DELETE *`

Answer (score 2):

Simply combine the conditions with an `OR` clause:

```
DELETE
FROM        Test 
WHERE       Followers BETWEEN 1 AND 9
    OR      Followers >1000
```